# thread-safe alternative for std::map?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdmap

I have a parallized loop and write access to a `std::map`. I would like to different parts of the map at the same time, i.e. I want to access map[a] and map[b] for a,b different. At  I found out that this is not possible, I wonder, however, if there is a good alternative or how to achieve this in a different way!

Comment: why not use a critical section or mutex to protect access to the std::map?

Comment: When you say "this is not possible" what do you mean by that? How did you figure that out? Do you possible have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show what you do?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You can't prove UB with a SSCCE. The statement is reasonable in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe that modifying existing elements to a map is safe as long as you're not touching the same elements (as this does not modify the underlying structure of the map). So if you insert `map[a]` and `map[b]` ahead of time, your separate threads should be able to modify those existing elements.

That said, it's probably cleaner and safer just to use normal synchronization techniques such as mutexes to protect access to the map.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to mutate `map[a]` and `map[b]` separately, as long as you do not mutate the underling `map`.

If you wish to mutate an associative container concurrently, check out `concurrent_unordered_map` from PPL or TBB.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could try giving each worker its own copy of the map and then merging the results. This way no locking would be needed at all.